# Sql return table information by username

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to receive all table information for the submited tablename in a stored procedure.

For example something like this :

```
create proc selectUserTable 
@username nvarchar(30)
as
begin
select * from @username
end
```

Of course this doesn't work, but how can I make something like that?

If I do this:

```
create proc selectUserTable 
@username nvarchar(30)
    as
    begin
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '@username'
end
```

It will only return the tablename not the information in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic query, but be aware of sql injection:

```
create proc selectUserTable 
@username nvarchar(30)
as
begin
  Exec('select * from ' +  @username)
end
```

If @tablename = 'users; drop table users;', you will be in trouble.
Better first get objectid by tablename variable then again get objectname by objectid and pass it to exec function, rather then passing tablename variable directly.

Comment: And how would you do it if you want to create a table. And you want to name the table with a incoming parameter called username?

Comment: @tosorro, the same way. Create dynamic query and pass it to EXEC function

Comment: I've tried a lot but it won't work. Please see my code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
create proc createTable
@username
as
begin
  exec ('create table '+@username + '(

  id int,
  ritnaam varchar(50),
  naam varchar(50)
  )')
end
```

Something like this?